# Merging two lines in a table when clicking "Save" or switching formular entry

Tags: ms-access, merge

We have created an MS access DB. Now we have a complicated form. It consists of a main form and a subform.

The problem is, when we enter data into the forms, 2 database entries are created. We would like to merge these entries into one each time the database is saved or if a user switches from one database entry within the form to the next one.

For this we would like to trigger a query which groups the different lines within the table.

Is it possible to trigger a query when switching entries within a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Assuming by "switching entries" you mean moving to a different record, use the form's `On Current` event. It fires every time a different record is selected/displayed. You can assign any VBA code or Macro to run when the event is fired, including executing a query.